# substitution into a partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

When substituting:

\begin{equation}
u = tF(\frac{x}{t})
\end{equation}

into
\begin{equation}
u_t = u^2_x \\
\end{equation}

The solution is given as: $ F - rF' = F'^2$

where $ r = \frac{x}{t} $ and $F = F(r)$

I think this is how the solution is found:

So I get:
\begin{align}
u_t & = u_t + u_rr_t \\
 & = F(r) + tF'(r)\left(\frac{-x}{t^2}\right) \\
& = F - \frac{x}{t}F \\
& = F - rF'\\
\\
u_x & =u_rr_x \\
& = tF'(r)\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\\
& = F'\\
\end{align}

This yields the desired solution of  $F - rF' = F'^2$

When substituting
\begin{equation}
x - \frac{4ut}{x} = F\left(\frac{u}{x}\right) \\
\end{equation}

Into
\begin{equation}
u_t = u^2_x \\
\end{equation}

The solution is given as $rF' - F = 0$ where here $r = \frac{u}{x} $

I have managed to get the first one, but now I need to know how to arrive at the second solution.